# Redirecting with htaccess rewrite map

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using following code to redirect all url with capital case latter in it to equalant small-case version of same url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
```

so anything like `http://host/InDex.php` is being redirected to `http://host/index.php`

But i need this behaviour only for cakephp routed urls. `app/users/1` not for files that exists on server.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that `RewriteMap` is not allowed in `.htaccess`. It needs to go in Apache config e.g. `httpd.conf`, once that is done replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^A-Z]*[A-Z].*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.